# Can freetype functions accept Unicode filenames?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, freetype

I have an MSVC project that uses freetype, and now I'm trying to move it to Unicode. But the freetype functions don't accept LPCTSTR arguments for file paths, they want "const char*". So code like

```
    WINDOWS_FONT WindowsFont;
    // ....
    FT_New_Face (pLibrary, WindowsFont.pszFileName, i, &face); // WindowsFont.pszFileName is LPTSTR
```

used to work when the project was ascii but not anymore when it's Unicode. Is there a way to make freetype accept Unicode filenames, some preprocessor define to switch it to unicode maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no wfopen in C++ standard (2003). Since freetype is meant to be portable, it only uses fopen, which can only accept const char* filenames. So, either load file to memory (or memory map it) and then use FT_New_Memory_Face to create font or convert wchar_t pszFileName into 8-bit encoding, potentially losing characters due to impossible conversion.

**On linux**, you could attempt to use `setlocale` so fopen will accept UTF8 strings, convert wchar_t string to UTF8. However **on windows [it won't work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**. So either load file to memory, or convert pszFileName to 8-bit encoding, then pass it to FT_New_Face.

Comment: On Windows, there is no way to open files using UTF-8 encoded file paths, so I guess the only approach would be the memory face option.

Comment: You can get the short filename of the file and pass that.

Comment: Also you should not be using wchar_t strings as filenames on Linux. On Linux a filename is natively char* and may not even be in a known locale encoding, so converting between encodings isn't possible. You should simply treat a filename from the user as an opaque block of data.

Comment: @bames53: Good idea, but it's possible for a file not to have a short name.  But Windows does support symlinks now, so you could use one to give the file an ASCII name.

Comment: @dan04 Yeah, and unfortunately Microsoft announced a while ago that they were eventually going to eliminate short names altogether in some future version of Windows. Soon there will be no way to open certain files in standard C++.

Comment: I wish Microsoft would support UTF-8 as an ANSI code page; it would make writing cross-platform C++ programs so much easier.  But that's probably why they don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to follow the framework's convention and import `tchar.h`, then use `_tfopen` instead (and switching to `LPCTSTR`, `_T("your_string")`, etc.). This will let you compile the same code for Linux and Windows with almost no change, while supporting either UTF-16 or UTF-8 in the code.

Comment: Do you mean change the source code of freetype itself and recompile it?

Comment: If possible/practical... it obviously depends on how many places you would need to do this in, but if it's only a few places it might be worth it.

Comment: This would really require **a lot of work**. Much simpler is to leave everything narrow-char in freetype, but replace `ft_fopen` to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 and call `wfopen` on Windows. Then `FT_New_Face` would magically support UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FT_Open_Face method, and it need a FT_Open_Args struct as argument.
In FT_Open_Args.stream, you can set customs read and close callback, and FreeType can read font data from any stream you want.

good luck